# Inno setup Error Invalid number of parameters on end;?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I do not know why show the error.
Sorry for my english, i from polish.

```
[Tasks]
Name: czysto; Description: "Instalacja na CZYSTO (Kasuje zawartosc RES_MODS - ZALECANE!)"; Components: Dictionaries; Flags: exclusive
Name: normalna; Description: "Normalna Instalacja (dla zaawansowanych użytkowników)"; Components: Dictionaries; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: cache; Description: "Wyczysc pliki CACHE"; GroupDescription: "Dodatki:"; Components: Dictionaries; Flags: unchecked

[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) and IsTaskSelected('czysto') then
  DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\test*'))
end; ERROR HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Text Error: Invalid number of parameters.

Help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DelTree](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_deltree.htm) takes several more parameters than the one you're supplying.

```
function DelTree(const Path: String; 
  const IsDir, DeleteFiles, DeleteSubdirsAlso: Boolean): Boolean;
```

You should bookmark the [Inno Setup documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp) for future reference.

Comment: My code now looks like this, and it still shows an error but I do not know whether I've changed. `code [code]
function DelTree(const Path: String;
  const IsDir, DeleteFiles, DeleteSubdirsAlso: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) and IsTaskSelected('czysto') then - ERROR HERE (Unknown Indentifer: `CurPageID`)
  DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\test*'))
end; `

Comment: You've fixed nothing. You're sill calling DelTree with one parameter where it expects 4. The declaration I provided does not get added to your code - it's how InnoSetup defines the function, and how you're supposed to use it. **Provide the additional three parameters when you call it.** And **read the documentation I linked, which tells you what those missing parameters are for. It's extremely difficult to help someone who refuses to accept the help. I went to the trouble to explain the problem and find the documentation links for you; the very least you could do is click on them and **read**.